# Dismissing presentedViewController also close the presenting view controller

Tags: ios, swift

this simple code doesn't behave as expected, and I was hoping for you to tell me if you have an idea of what could be the problem.

```
let vc = UIViewController()
self.present(vc, animated: true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
    vc.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

here the dismiss method called after 3 seconds also pop (!) the `self` view controller.
the parent view controller is not presented modaly.

This bug originally happen in a real life situation : a UIImagePicker poping its presentor viewController when trying to dismiss.

I'm open to suggestion !
Thanks

EDIT : this happens in iOS 12.1 but not in iOS 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the presenting view controller was a child view controller,

this snippet behave as intended :

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

self.present(vc, animated: true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
    vc.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If self presents, then self dismisses. ;)

```
let vc = UIViewController()
self.present(vc, animated: true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hello! dismiss on self was not doing anything, allegedly for the same reason. Thanks!

Comment: ?? Weird, I did the test before posting the answer, and did not notice any bug. Maybe could you be more specific. What do you mean by "self being popped"?

Comment: Have you tried it on iOS 12.1? by "self" being closed was in fact the parent of the child that was dismissed.